# Create a dataframe from another data frame based on column containing string (2 defined conditions)

Tags: python, pandas

Iam trying to compile some of the columns in df1 to a new dataframe df2.

the columns will be selected based on the following conditions:

1. if word 'COORDINATES' is in the column
2. if word 'ID' is in the column

Here is the code I tried:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(csvpath) #table as below

cols = [col for col in df1.columns if  'Coordinates' and 'ID' in col]

df2=df1[cols]
```

However the conditions are only being applied for the last item in cols= (in this case its only extracting ID and ignoring coordinates)

How do i edit the above code to include both Coordinates and ID (I could just drop the unwanted columns however the dataset im dealing with is large and hence i need to do it in such a way similar to what i defined above)

much appreciated your help on this.

Original Table (df1)

[image]

Required Output(df2)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
cols = [col for col in df1.columns if  'Coordinates' in col or 'ID' in col]
```

Comment: i tried that, it takes the whole df. any other suggestions?

Comment: are you sure, I just tried it on my computer using the same column names as you have and it worked fine